# How to best parallelize nested for loop that calls a variable update function?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I'm trying to parallelize a nested for loop in OpenMP (C++) that sort of looks like this:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++){
   for(j = 0 ; j < a.size() ; j++){
      if(i!=j)
         a[i].update(a[j]);
   }
}
```

Where the whole jist is that the value of a[i] gets updated by the value of a[j]. The problem that I see here is that there's a dependency in which the update() method might use an old value of a[i], before it gets updated. I have a few ideas in mind involving collapse, shared and private variables, albeit I cannot test them as the server that I need to run this on is currently down, meaning I can't test my theories, so I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction -- What would be the correct pragma clauses that would allow me to execute this in parallel, efficiently?

My thoughts were to maybe keep i private and have a shared j so that the values that do get changed don't depend on one another, although it feels like that would create another dependency in which j might be equal to another i.

**UPDATE 1:**
Is `#pragma omp critical` what I'm looking for?

**UPDATE 2:**
Upon further analysis, I have realized that the attribute that gets updated is not relevant to the entire operation, so there is no race between what the current value of a[j] is. Nevertheless, I still can't figure out how to parallelize this as update is a void method that depends on the previous value of a[i] (something like `a[i]+= f(a[j]);`. Return type can't be changed, so atomic struct won't work since there is no explicit operation, neither will a reduction struct, whereas critical just lets it go in serial mode. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Regarding your update 2: as mentioned by @VictorEijkhout the problem is here is the dependency, which prevents any parallelization of the `i` loop. However, if your update is really equivalent to `a[i] += f(a[j])`, then parallelizing the `j` loop with a `reduction` clause should be possible.

Comment: @PierU would the same apply in the case of update() handling ```a[i].attributeX += f(a[j].attributeY)```? Asking for a separate instance

Comment: I think it would be OK, as the values of `attributeY` are not modified during the iterations. This is however is different algorithm.

Comment: @pron1ghtmare360 can't you really share more about the update method? maybe by seeing a bit more of the method would help us

Answer (score 2):

In each `i` iteration, `a[i]` gets updated both with `a[j]` for `j<i` and `j>i`. The second category poses no problem, so let's completely ignore that. You could make a copy of `a` and read those elements from that copy. Your problem is with `j<i` because then you update with elements that themselves have been updated. In effect, `a[i]` depends on `a[i-1]` and lower indices. You have a dependency, and no critical/atomic will solve that.

So the `i` loop needs to be serial. Depending on the structure of your `update` function it may be possible to compute the updates for all `j<i` in parallel with some reduction, and then apply that to `a[i]`. But if the update function is complicated, even that may not be possible: in effect you'd have quantities `a[i,j]` that depend on `a[i,j-1]` and the whole thing is serial.

Comment: I updated the question to tackle the dependency mentioned in the beginning, as it isn't an issue overall. I rephrased the question to make it clearer (see Update 2:)

Comment: @pron1ghtmare360 in your update you wrote `a[i]+= f(a[i])`. is that right, an `i` in the rhs? Should be `j`? In the latter case, a plus reduction over `j` would make it parallel.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Are we talking about
```#pragma omp for reduction(+: j)```
or
```#pragma omp for reduction(+: a[j])```
?

Comment: @pron1ghtmare360 the reduction clause needs the result variable, so that's `a[i]`. I would introduce a temporary variable for it.